# Summing with assumptions provides unexpected output

Tags: symbolic, summation, assumptions

I am computing a closed form of a number of sums having generally the following form: $$ \sum_{i = 0}^{m/2}\sum_{\substack{0\leq k \leq i \\ 2k \equiv i + m \, \text{mod } 3}} k $$

It looks like Mathematica can handle this depending on the residue of $m$ mod 12, so I've been breaking it into different cases.

What I've noticed is that I get a closed form solution with the condition that $m>0$:

Input:

```
Sum[3*k, {i, 0, (m - 4)/2}, {k, Mod[(m + i)/2, 3]/3, i/3}, 
 Assumptions -> m >0 && Mod[m, 12] == 4]
```

Output:

$$ \begin{cases} \frac{2}{3} & m = 4 \\ \frac{1}{288}(-92 - 9m + 12m^2
+ 2m^3) & \text{True} \end{cases} $$

whereas the same command but changing the condition to $m > 4$ yields a rather messy answer:

Input:

```
Sum[3*k, {i, 0, (m - 4)/2}, {k, Mod[(m + i)/2, 3]/3, i/3}, 
  Assumptions -> m >4 && Mod[m, 12] == 4]
```

Output:

```
1/144 (-48 + 8 m + 6 m^2 + m^3 + 24 Mod[m/2, 3] + 
   24 Floor[1/12 (-4 + m)] Mod[m/2, 3] - 24 Mod[m/2, 3]^2 - 
  ...
  24 Mod[(5 + m)/2, 3]^2 - 24 Floor[1/12 (-14 + m)] Mod[(5 + m)/2, 3]^2)
```

Not sure which computation to trust as I am a bit ignorant to what is going on under the hood here. Any suggestions on best practices for computations of this type or an explanation of what might be causing this?

Comment: Perhaps try reformulating your sum using [Iverson brackets](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IversonBracket.html)? `Sum[k Boole[Mod[2 k, 3] == Mod[i + m, 3]], {i, 0, m/2}, {k, 0, i}]`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. For me that particular command evaluates to a pretty long sum as well with a lot of  `Boole[Mod[3 + m, 3] == 1] ` type terms. Should I be trying anything else to simplify there?